# How to add ITable (Table object) to current map (or document)?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, table

I created an in-memory results ITable and I need to add it to the current ArcMap document/map to see the generated data.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try creating a new IStandaloneTable,  assign your table to IStandaloneTable.Table, cast the focus map to IStandaloneTableCollection, and add the standalonetable to it.

Might need to call IMxDocument.UpdateContents too.